# Convert columns into rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
+--------------+-------+--------+----------+
| attribute_id | color | brand  | category |
+--------------+-------+--------+----------+
|            1 | red   | honda  | cars     |
|            2 | blue  | bmw    | cars     |
|            3 | pink  | skonda | vans     |
+--------------+-------+--------+----------+
```

I would like to convert it to the following:

```
+--------------+---------+
| attribute_id | keyword |
+--------------+---------+
|            1 | red     |
|            2 | blue    |
|            3 | pink    |
|            1 | honda   |
|            2 | bmw     |
|            3 | skonda  |
|            1 | cars    |
|            2 | cars    |
|            3 | vans    |
+--------------+---------+
```

The only way I can think of is to use `UNION`s like this:

```
SELECT attribute_id, color from attributes 
UNION ALL
SELECT attribute_id, brand from attributes
UNION ALL
SELECT attribute_id, category from attributes
```

The above way is a bit cumbersome, especially since my real use case will need to join multiple tables for each select.

Is there a simpler or less *copy/paste* way to write this?

Comment: More important is *what* are you trying to do with the data?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO - I have a poorly designed table with many columns, I  would like to populate my newly created keywords table. I will be using each of the columns from the original table as a keyword.

Comment: I would just select * from your table normally, then process it in whatever language you are using instead.

Comment: @BrianGlaz My language is MySQL, I'm just trying to populate another table with the results. It would be too slow to process with PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more efficient query (at least for large tables) is:

```
SELECT attribute_id,
       (case when n = 1 then color
             when n = 2 then brand
             when n = 3 then category
        end) as keyword
from attributes a cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3) n;
```

The reason this is better than the `union all` query is performance.  The `union all` will scan the original table three times.  This will scan the original table once (and then loop through `n`).  For a large table this could be a significant difference in performance.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the technique. I have never found a use for cross joins before.